Flutter Firebase Error, Null check Operator on Null value
I am getting Null check Operator on Null value in the following code
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              Map<String, dynamic> productData = snapshot.data!.data()!;
              // Map<String, dynamic>? productData = snapshot.data?
              // .data(); //I have also tried this but does not work!

              List<dynamic> imageUrls = productData['images'];
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: size.width * 1.2,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                          child: imageUrls[0]),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: size.width * 0.06,
                          vertical: size.height * 0.02),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                productData['title'],
                                style: customTextgrey.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: size.width * 0.044),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                productData['quantity'],
                                style: customTextgreen.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: size.width * 0.03),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.6),
                            child: Text(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              productData['price'],
                              style: customTextblue.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: size.width * 0.05),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: size.height * 0.015,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.624),
                            child:
                                const CustomGreyText(title: 'Installment Plan'),
                          ),
                          const InstallmentPlanSection(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                right: size.width * 0.624,
                                top: size.height * 0.011),
                            child: const CustomGreyText(title: 'About Product'),
                          ),
                          AboutProduct(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }

I have tried almost all soluitions on internet but nothing seems to work for me
i am trying to get data from firebase
i have tried only using snapshot.hasData in the if else but no luck
if i use snapshot.data==null then the code works but shows Else statement in this case Not data Available

Did you debug and check what snapshot.data actually is? Your runtime error says the call to .data() returns null. There is little we can do about it. You can either work with that, or go to the previous part of your program and check why.

it is fixed thankyou i forgot to pass productId which was causing it null!

There isn't enough information to be able to help you... What type of object is "snapshot"?

it was a logical error i had to pass product ID to the widget which is why it was causing null

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
